# PyYAML path at serialization time vs deserialization time

Tags: python, serialization, yaml, pyyaml

I am working on a game engine which includes a simple GUI development tool.  The GUI tool allows a user to define various entities and components, which can then be saved in a configuration file.  When the game engine runtime loads the configuration file, it can determine how to create the various entities and components for use in the game.

For a configuration file saving mechanism, I am using PyYAML.  The issue that I am having stems from the fact that the serialization process occurs in a module which is in a different directory than the module which loads and parses the file through PyYAML.

**Simplified Serializer**

```
import yaml

def save_config(context, file_name):
    config_file = file(file_name, 'w')
    # do some various processing on the context dict object
    yaml.dump(context, config_file)
    config_file.close()
```

This takes the `context` object, which is a `dict` that represents various game objects, and writes it to a config file.  This works without issue.

**Simplified Deserializer in engine**

```
import yaml

def load(file_name):
    config_file = open(file_name, 'r')
    context = yaml.load(config_file)
    return context
```

This is where the problem occurs.  On `yaml.load(config_file)`, I will receive an error, because it fails to find a various name on a certain module.  I understand why this is happening.  For example, when I serialize the config file, it will list an `AssetComponent` (a component type in the engine) as being at `engine.common.AssetComponent`.  However, from the deserializer's perspective, the `AssetComponent` should just be at `common.AssetComponent` (because the deserialization code itself exists within the `engine` package), so it fails to find it under `engine`.

Is there a way to manually handle paths when serializing or deserializing with PyYAML?  I would like to make sure they both happen from the same "perspective."

**Edit:**
The following shows what a problematic config file might look like, followed by what the manually corrected config would look like

**Problematic**

```
!!python/object/apply:collections.defaultdict
args: [!!python/name:__builtin__.dict ''] 
dictitems:
  assets:
  - !!python/object:common.Component
    component: !!python/object:engine.common.AssetComponent {file_name: ../content/sticksheet.png,
      surface: null}
    text: ../content/sticksheet.png
    type_name: AssetComponent
```

**Corrected**

```
!!python/object/apply:collections.defaultdict
args: [!!python/name:__builtin__.dict ''] 
dictitems:
  assets:
  - !!python/object:tools.common.Component
    component: !!python/object:common.AssetComponent {file_name: ../content/sticksheet.png,
      surface: null}
    text: ../content/sticksheet.png
    type_name: AssetComponent
```

Comment: Can you add an example of a config file that displays the problem?

Comment: Do the serialization and deserialization routines each have their own `__main__` routine?

Comment: The serialization and deserialization routines do not each have their own `__main__` routines, however they are each called by separate modules which have their own `__main__` routines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem lies in a mismatch between your package structure and your `__main__` routines. The module containing your `__main__` will be **inside** a package, but it has no way of knowing that. So, therefore, you will use imports relative to the location of the file containing `__main__` and not relative to the top level structure of your package.

See [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/python-relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time) for a longer (and probably better) explanation.

So, how can you fix it?

Inside the file containing `__main__` you do:

```
from tools.common import Component
# instead of from common import Component

c = Component()
print yaml.dump(c)
```

Another thing you must ensure is that python will know how to load your modules. If you have installed your package this will be done automatically, but during development this is usually not the case. So during development you will also want to make your development modules findable.

The easiest way (but not very clean) is to use `sys.path.append('the directory containing tools and engine')`. Another way (cleaner) is to set the PYTHONPATH environment variable to include your top level directory containing `tools` and `engine`.

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly [declare the Python type of an object](http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation#Objects) in a YAML document:

```yaml
!!python/object:module_foo.ClassFoo {
    attr_foo: "spam",
    …,
}
```

Comment: I've been doing something similar in order to at least be able to continue working, by doing some strategic search/replace.  The challenge is in getting this to happen automatically, for any arbitrary object which resides in either the `tools` package (where the serializer is) or the `engine` package (where the deserializer is).

Comment: Please update the question to show how you're already using this, and explain in the question why this documented feature isn't meeting your requirements.

Comment: I'm using it by doing search/replace on the saved YAML file after serializing the structure.  This doesn't meet the requirements because I don't see anything in the documentation about how to (at runtime) change the path in the `!!python/object` tags.  For example: currently it is serializing something at `!!python/object:common.Component` and I want it to instead save it as `!!python/object:tools.common.Component` so that it resolves properly when deserialized from an arbitrary location.